# Short Circuit AND, OR and Precedence Table

Tags: java

Hello i have a question regarding precedence Table in java. It says && has a higher precedence over ||.

```
boolean b,c,d;
b = c = d = false;
boolean e = (b = true) || (c = true) && (d = true);
System.out.println(b+" "+c+" "+d);
```

When i run mentioned code code it output "true false false". why doesn't it evaluate c = true && d = true part first since && has a higher precedence? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

The JVM evaluates `b = true` which returns true. Therefore, the expression

```
boolean e = (b = true) || (c = true) && (d = true);
```

is equivalent to

```
boolean e = true || (c = true) && (d = true);
```

which always results in `true` without the need to "evaluate" `c = true` and `d = true`.

In other words, `boolean e = (b = true) || (c = true) && (d = true);` is similar to:

```
boolean e;
if(b = true) {
    e = true;
} else if((c = true) && (d = true)) {
    e = true;
} else {
    e = false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The precedence here just means that

```
X || Y && Z
```

is equivalent to:

```
X || (Y && Z)
```

That executes as:

- Evaluate X
- If X is `true`, the result is `true`
- Otherwise, evaluate `Y`

  - If `Y` is false, the result of `Y && Z` is `false`, so the overall result is `false`
  - Otherwise, evaluate `Z`
  - If the result is `true`, then `Y && Z` is `true`, so the overall result is `true`
  - If the result is `false`, then `Y && Z` is `false`, so the overall result is `false

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought higher precedence means (Y && Z) part get evaluated before the X so both Y and Z get equals to true and JVM doesn't bother to check X since one side of the || is true..